# how to open webform page in new tab of browser?

Tags: c#

In GridView, I bound columns so by click on name column I have to open his/her information in new form page that have to open in new window so how to do it?

I tried lots like below..

```
protected void gridCustomer_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "VIEW")
    {
        int row = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        Session["UserId"] = row;
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('../Update Pages/RegCustUpdateAndDelete.aspx', target='_blank');", true);
        Response.Write("<script>window.open( '../Update Pages/RegCustUpdateAndDelete.aspx','_blank');</script>");
        //Response.Write("<script>window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href</script>");
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "refresh", "window.setTimeout('window.location.reload(true);',5000);", true);
        //Response.End();
        // Response.Redirect("CustomerSearch.aspx");
    }
}
```

It was work some days back but now not one of code working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code..

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('../Update Pages/RegCustUpdateAndDelete.aspx','_blank');", true);
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: is it possible to do this after a certain method on code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better if you make the grid column as a link or hyperlink using Itemtemplate and give Target attribute as _blank.

Comment: Iam using link button..so how to use Target attribute as _blank.?